# Simplest form for $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(ax)}{b+x}~dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Regarding the integral, $$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(ax)}{b+x}~dx,~~~~a>0\land b>0$$

Let $t=ax$

$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{ab+t}~dt$$

Let $\theta=ab+t$

$$\begin{align} I&=\int_{ab}^\infty \frac{\sin(\theta-ab)}{\theta}~d\theta\\
\\
&=\cos(ab)\int_{ab}^\infty \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta}~d\theta-\sin(ab)\int_{ab}^\infty \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\theta}~d\theta\\
\\
&=\cos(ab)\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta}~d\theta-\cos(ab)\int_{0}^{ab} \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta}~d\theta-\sin(ab)\int_{ab}^\infty \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\theta}~d\theta \end{align}$$

Define the [sine integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) and [cosine integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html) as: $$\text{Si}(z)=\int_0^z \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta}d\theta,~~~~~\text{Ci}(z)=-\int_z^\infty \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\theta}d\theta$$

We get:

$$\boxed{\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(ax)}{b+x}~dx=\frac\pi2\cos(ab)-\cos(ab)\text{Si}(ab)+\sin(ab)\text{Ci}(ab)~}$$

**Question:**

Is this the simplest form we can get for this integral?

Comment: You may be able to use the imaginary part of the [Ei function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) or the Ei function at complex arguments to rewrite the Si and Ci functions